# CodeIgniter Form Validation Not Working

Tags: php, html, validation, codeigniter, webforms

Can't seem to get form validation working on code igniter, unsure what's wrong!

Here's my controller class:

```
class registerController extends MY_Controller {

    // --- Methods -----------------

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->firephp->log('REGISTER PAGE CONTROLLER ACTIVE');

        //Load user model
        $this->load->model('usersModel');

        //load form validation
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

    }

    //------------------------------

    public function register()
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('registerForenameFieldName', 'Fist Name', 'required');

        //This is executed when the form is submitted
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {

            $this->firephp->log('Registration form validation failed');

            //Load in the views
            $this->load->view('global/head.php');
            $this->load->view('global/top.php');
            $this->load->view('register/register.php');
            $this->load->view('global/footer.php');

        } else {

            $this->firephp->log('Registration form validation succeeded');

            //Model method here

            //Load in the views
            $this->load->view('global/head.php');
            $this->load->view('global/top.php');
            $this->load->view('home.php');
            $this->load->view('global/footer.php');
        }

    }

}
```

and my form:

```
<?php  echo form_open('register'); ?>

    <div id="registerErrors"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></div>

        <table id="registerTable">

            <tr>
            <td class="regLeftCell"><p>First Name</p></td>
            <td class="regRightCell">
            <input id="registerForenameField" class="textField registerField" name="registerForenameFieldName" type="text" placeholder="Forename" value="<?php echo set_value('registerForenameFieldName'); ?>"></input>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="regLeftCell"><p>Last Name</p></td>
            <td class="regRightCell">
            <input id="registerSurnameField" class="textField registerField" name="registerSurnameFieldName" type="text" placeholder="Surname" value="<?php echo set_value('registerSurnameFieldName'); ?>"></input>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="regLeftCell"><p>Email Address</p></td>
            <td class="regRightCell">
            <input id="registerEmailField" class="textField registerField" name="registerEmailFieldName" type="text" placeholder="Email Address"></input>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="regLeftCell"><p>Choose Password</p></td>
            <td class="regRightCell">
            <input id="registerPasswordField" class="textField registerField" name="registerPasswordFieldName" type="text" placeholder="Password"></input>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="regLeftCell"><p>Confirm Password</p></td>
            <td class="regRightCell">
            <input id="registerConfirmPasswordField" class="textField registerField" name="registerConfirmPasswordFieldName" type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password"></input>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="regLeftCell"><p>Address Line 1</p></td>
            <td class="regRightCell">
            <input id="registerAddress1Field" class="textField registerField" name="registerAddress1FieldName" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 1"></input>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="regLeftCell"><p>Address Line 2</p></td>
            <td class="regRightCell">
            <input id="registerAddress2Field" class="textField registerField" name="registerAddress2FieldName" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 2"></input>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="regLeftCell"><p>Address Line 3</p></td>
            <td class="regRightCell">
            <input id="registerAddress3Field" class="textField registerField" name="registerAddress3FieldName" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 3"></input>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="regLeftCell"><p>Post Code</p></td>
            <td class="regRightCell">
            <input id="registerAddressPostCodeField" class="textField registerField" name="registerPostCodeFieldName" type="text" placeholder="Post Code"></input>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="regLeftCell"><p>Country</p></td>
            <td class="regRightCell">
            <input id="registerAddressCountryField" class="textField registerField" name="registerSurnameFieldName" type="text" placeholder="Country"></input>
            </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <div id="registerButton">
            <input class="button registerSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Register"/>
        </div>


    </form>
```

The routing is set up like this:

```
$route['register'] = 'registerController/register';
```

What's wrong? It just fails every time without displaying an error.

It just reloads the same page with no validation errors. The $this->form_validation->run() evaluates at FALSE every time because I have logged it in FirePHP, a Firebug extension.

EDIT:

It may also be worth mentioning that I get a 404 error in the console despite it loading the page:

[image: other error]

Comment: Did you try changing the name of the last input which is also `registerSurnameFieldName`?

Comment: ah, well spotted but that wasn't it! Driving me crazy, can't for the life of me see what's wrong!

Comment: Does it validate when you change the `required` to something like `trim`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have FINALLY found the answer! My server wasn't configured correctly, I didn't have mod_rewrite enabled so none of the requests were working properly or something.

Ubuntu users, fire this off on the command line to enable it:
sudo a2enmod rewrite

Then restart Apache.

I am using the following .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: this solved my issue, all GET/POST requests were getting 404 and i had a similar .htaccess. `a2enmod rewrite` enabled mod_rewrite and everything is good, thanks.

Comment: I tried this, But I was getting a 404 error for every request

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give the controller name in the `form_open` function, it should be

```
<?php  echo form_open('registerController/register'); ?>
```

**Documentation:** [**Form Helper**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html).

Comment: Tried that without luck. Shouldn't the routing sort that out for me anyway though? $route['register'] = 'registerController/register';

Comment: Are you sure the controller gets executed ? try something to make sure that your controller/constructor is being executed.

Comment: Yeh, the form validation function is being executed because I have put $this->firephp->log('Registration form validation failed'); in the $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE condition and that gets logged every time.

Comment: Not sure but try to add another rule as `xss_clean|required`.

Comment: no luck, i think it's something to do with that 404 in firebug on the picture. no idea though. very stuck

Comment: Your path is not valid, in the image of firebug it shows that `http://127.0.0.1:4567/Tat/register` is not found.

Comment: but it loads the page ok when i visit that url?

Comment: May nbe it loads for the first time and not submitted on the second time, not sure but 404 is appearing, so it means it's not found or not submitted to the correct controller/path.

Answer (score 0):

1. What does it mean - "fails every time" - display empty page? or error? or what?
2. Is constructor executing?

   ```
   function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
       var_dump('contructor');
   }
   ```
3. Is register function called?

   ```
   function register()
   {
       var_dump('register function');
   }
   ```

Or just add

```
$this->firephp->log('Registration function');
```

At the beginning of the `register` function and let us know your debugging results.

Have you tried example from here:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: Yeah, all are getting called. It just reloads the same page with no validation errors. The $this->form_validation->run() evaluates at FALSE every time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your __construct:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

then try this:

```
echo form_open(site_url("register"));
```

the function site_url may help you use the routed url.
if this help nothing,you could try echo base_url(); and other url helper function to complete the url.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why people are loading an extension for printing variables and arrays in firebug. For most projects im using this: Ist the same. You dont need firephp core. And you dont need firephp addon for firebug.

```
<?php
$debug[] = 'Hello World';
// and/or
$debug[] = array('a1'=>"ArrValue1",'a2'=>"ArrValue2");
?>

<!-- add before </body>... -->
<?php if(isset($debug)): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    <?php foreach($debug as $js): if(is_array($js)) $js= json_encode($js); else $js = '"'.$js.'"'; ?>
    console.log(<?php echo $js; ?>);
    <?php endforeach; ?>
})
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```